# Suggest a sql query for requirement

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Case-1**

| id | A |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | a1 |
| 102 | a2 |
| 103 | a3 |

| id | B |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 0 |
| 103 | 0 |

**Case-2**

| id | A |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | a1 |
| 102 | a2 |
| 103 | a3 |

| id | B |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 |
| 102 | 0 |
| 103 | 0 |

There are two tables, I am selecting 2 columns "id", "B" joined with left join.

That is I need the result set only when there is at least one non null value in the column B. If I use the inner join, rows which are having 0 are missing. I need the complete column to generate incase of at least one non null value present.

In picture-1, the result set required is (101,2),(102,0),(103,0). This I can achieve through left join.

In case-2(pic-2), the result set required is null.

I use postgresql

Comment: You need more explanation and consistency. Is Case-1 and picture-1 the same thing? You also indicate there should non empty result set when *least one non null value present*, but then say case-2 should generate an empty result set. However in case-2 there are no null values ( 0 is a value, it is NOT). Finally, why a join since the output in both cases can be obtained from just (id, B)?

Comment: Hi @Belayer, thanks for your time in replying my question. And sorry for being so obscure in details in asking question. I asked the same question can you please answer this. I will delete this question. the link to the new question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468033/please-suggest-an-sql-query-based-on-the-requirement