# Please suggest an sql query based on the requirement

Tags: postgresql

I have a dynamic sql, where I need to **select** two columns(say A & B) from the table. I need to generate the result set only if column B has at least one non zero value. If there is no non zero value in the column B, result set should be empty.

Comment: So if there are 100 rows with a zero value and one row with a non-zero value you want all those 101 rows?

Comment: Please some sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your reply. Yes that's what is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be that simple, just as you wrote the rule -

```sql
select a, b 
from the_table
where exists (select from the_table where b <> 0);
```